# How to prove a GCD question?

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

Prove for all positive integers d, m, n. If d=gcd(m, n) then gcd(m, nk)=gcd(m, dk).

So I messed around with it, and I started from the conclusion. I made gcd(m, nk)=x, gcd(m, dk)=y. Then by Bezout's Lemma ms+nkt=x, ms+dkt=y, s and t are integers. I think I can make these 2 equations and change it to the form of d=gcd(m, n). Maybe by dividing? But If I divide it by d, then ms/d+nkt/d=x/d, then this equation might not be integers anymore. I don't know that the next step is. Thank you for looking this over for me.

Comment: This is copy-paste from [here](https://www.coursehero.com/tutors-problems/Algebra/27027276-Prove-that-for-all-positive-integers-d-m-and-n-if-d-gcdm-n-th/). Search this site for duplicates, too.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/242) in the dupe. **Or** reduce to the coprime case $\,(m,n)=1\,$ by cancelling $\,(m,n),$ throughout, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3471852/242). We have *many* quetions on this and related topics. Please search first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the GCD in prime factorization form.
If $m = \prod p_i ^ {m_i}, n = \prod p_i^{n_i}$, then $ d = \prod p_i^{\min(m_i, n_i)}$.

The result follows by showing that

$$ \min (m_i, n_i + k_i) = \min (m_i, \min (m_i, n_i) + k_i)$$

> A direct way of showing this is to condition on $ m_i \geq n_i$ (so $\min(m_i, n_i) = n_i$) and $ m_i < n_i$ (so both sides equal $m_i$).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it without the prime factorization form?